# Built-in power amplifier of the ST7580

Tags: power-line-communication, power-amplifier, st

The [ST7580](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/DM00045903.pdf) is a power line communication device that can be controlled with any host controller. The ST7580 has a buil in power amplifier to allow it to send a modulated signal (0Hz to 250kHz) as far as possible down the power line.

I have followed the [design guide](https://my.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/71/8d/7f/e6/13/68/46/46/DM00050178.pdf/files/DM00050178.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050178.pdf) to the letter apart from using the ST host controller and making slight alterations to the AFE (to choose a specific frequency band @ 100kHz with PSK), such as the transmission active filter, reception filter and the power, but only to the values the equations permitted.

[image]

I have a proper connection between the ST7580 and the host controller and I have set all the MIB setting I needed to as per the [user manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/8d/ce/5e/34/e0/03/41/ef/CD00270292.pdf/files/CD00270292.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00270292.pdf) and the system is running at the [appropriate speed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380355/how-to-get-8mhz-square-signal-out-a-pic18f45).

**But for some reason, I can not get a signal out of the power amplifier pin (PA_OUT).**

I have a correctly modulated signal being produced from the TX_OUT pin, as shown below in yellow, but the PA_OUT pin remains steady, as shown in red.

[image]

I have read through all the [application notes](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/interfaces-and-transceivers/power-line-transceivers/st7580.html) available and been in contact with the support at ST, but I am still having this problem.

If anyone has any **suggestions** or **ideas** on how to I can get this to work I would really appreciate the input.

PS: I have zero detection implemented and the system is exposed to mains.

[image]

I have tested the system with and without mains, as well as a hundred other tests.

Comment: 1) What's the trigger mode on the first scope image? It doesn't look like it's successfully triggered, and since you're using ALT, not CHOP your two traces are
from different times, which would explain why you're not seeing anything. 2) It's a little difficult to guess answers without the full schematic,
but what do you have around the CL pin, and have you checked [with your finger] that the chip isn't in thermal shutdown because something is pulling too much power
from one of the many LDOs in the pacakge (or you've pushed it into SCR latchup with
a wrongly sequenced input).

Comment: @james Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, the oscope that I have does not have a Chop option but I see what you are saying about the triggering. When I am only monitoring the PA_OUT pin, I get the same flat line. There is no signal out at all. 2) My schem is exactly the same as the design guide linked and the components around the CL are the same as the one in the design guide. The temp of the chip is warm but I can hold my finger on it. I have code that will stop using the chip until it is below a certain temp.

Comment: @james The St7580 is still responding and The TX_OUT is working, are you suggesting that a cluster of transistors on the PA are damaged (stuck in an SCR state)? is this still possible even if the chip is not hot? The Chip does not get above 70 degrees Celsius.

Comment: What power rail voltage (VCC) do you have on pin 24?

Comment: @Andyaka pin 24 is at 12V. I know it can go higher, but other systems connected to the sample power rail can only handle 12V. The ST7580 can work at 12V. Increasing the VCC to 18V will only increase the power out onto the mains signal. At this point, nothing is coming out of the PA_OUT. I have found out the VCC should drop a little when sending a message on mains, which makes sense, but I do not have any current limiting setups for the ST7580.